# Are both /etc/my.cnf and /etc/mysql/my.cnf needed?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, my.cnf

I recently setup a new web server with Ubuntu 12.04. I noticed that there are two my.cnf files, and MySQL successfully reads both:

- /etc/my.cnf
- /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Do I need to keep both of these files?

If possible, I would like to simply merge the lines from one my.cnf into the other, thereby having only one my.cnf to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only need one of those, but for legacy reasons MySQL will LOOK in those places (and a few others, some of them really strange, because that's how it is). Feel free to consolidate.